# Get Token from Azure using AAD App (ClientID, TenantID, Cert-Thumbprint)

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, client-certificates, azure-authentication

I have below Method to get a token from Azure using **ClientID**, **TenantID** and **AADAppPassword**

This is working awesome but now I need to switch to different **AAD AppID** and use **Certificate Thumbprint** Or **Certificate pfx**.
I don't want to change my 1000+ lines of code.

Can someone help me get a token the same way I'm getting using below Method but use **Certificate Thumbprint** instead and which returns **token** so that I can call the method right before I'm about to make rest API call.

```html
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientKey)
        {
            string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId;
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);
            var result = await authenticationContext

            .AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }
            string token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [ClientAssertionCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientassertioncertificate?view=azure-dotnet) instead of ClientCredential

```
X509Certificate2 cert = ReadCertificateFromStore(config.CertName);
certCred = new ClientAssertionCertificate(config.ClientId, cert);
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, certCred);
```

You may refer the [Azure AD v1 Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-certificate-credential/blob/master/TodoListDaemonWithCert-core/Program.cs#L66) for this.

MSAL.NET is now the recommended auth library to use with the Microsoft identity platform. No new features will be implemented on ADAL.NET. The efforts are focused on improving MSAL. You can refer the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration) here if you are planning to migrate applications to MSAL.NET